# Magento 2: How can I add custom attribute in order summery for checkout page?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, checkout, attributes

I am trying to display a product attribute value

I have found the template where it is displayed:

```
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html
```

How can I get the value of an attribute to display?

```
<div class="product-item-details">

    <div class="product-item-inner">
        <div class="product-item-name-block">
            <strong class="product-item-name" data-bind="text: $parent.name"></strong>
            <div class="details-qty">
                <span class="label"><!-- ko i18n: 'Qty' --><!-- /ko --></span>

                <span class="value" data-bind="text: $parent.qty"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('after_details') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>

    <!-- ko if: (JSON.parse($parent.options).length > 0)-->
    <div class="product options" data-bind="mageInit: {'collapsible':{'openedState': 'active'}}">
        <span data-role="title" class="toggle"><!-- ko i18n: 'View Details' --><!-- /ko --></span>
        <div data-role="content" class="content">
            <strong class="subtitle"><!-- ko i18n: 'Options Details' --><!-- /ko --></strong>
            <dl class="item-options">
                <!--ko foreach: JSON.parse($parent.options)-->
                <dt class="label" data-bind="text: label"></dt>
                    <!-- ko if: ($data.full_view)-->
                    <dd class="values" data-bind="html: full_view"></dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                    <!-- ko ifnot: ($data.full_view)-->
                    <dd class="values" data-bind="html: value"></dd>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </dl>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /ko -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set your custom attribute inside checkout page summary block using below way,

app/code/{Package}/{Module}/etc/di.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <!-- Set Custom attribute in chekcout page summary block -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="default_config_provider" type="Package\Module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

app/code/{Package}/{Module}/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php file

```
<?php
namespace Package\Module\Model;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Session as CheckoutSession;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface as QuoteItemRepository;

class DefaultConfigProvider
{
    private $checkoutSession;
    private $quoteItemRepository;
    protected $scopeConfig;

    public function __construct(
        CheckoutSession $checkoutSession,
        QuoteItemRepository $quoteItemRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->_scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->quoteItemRepository = $quoteItemRepository;
    }

    public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, $result)
    {        
        $quoteId = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();
        if ($quoteId) {            
            $itemOptionCount = count($result['totalsData']['items']);
            $quoteItems = $this->quoteItemRepository->getList($quoteId);

            $isbnOptions = array();
            foreach ($quoteItems as $index => $quoteItem) {
                $quoteItemId = $quoteItem['item_id'];
                $isbnOptions[$quoteItemId] = $quoteItem['isbn'];               
            }

            for($i=0;$i<$itemOptionCount;$i++){
                $quoteParentId = $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['item_id'];                    
                $currentOption = array();
                $currentOption = json_decode($result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['options'],true);

                $newOption = $isbnOptions[$quoteParentId];

                //for set new option inside current option tab
                if(count($newOption) > 0 && is_array($newOption)){                        
                    foreach($newOption as $key=>$value){
                        if( !is_array($value) ){
                            $currentOption[] = array('value'=>$value,'label'=>$key);
                        }
                    }
                    $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['options'] = json_encode($currentOption);
                }                    
            }
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, We can set the custom attribute in order summary in checkout.

Create a custom Extension

Step 1:
Declare plugin
app/code/{Package}/{Module}/etc/di.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <!-- Set Custom attribute in chekcout page summary block -->
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider">
        <plugin name="default_config_provider" type="Package\Module\Model\DefaultConfigProvider"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Step 2 :
Declare new file

> app/code/{Package}/{Module}/Model/DefaultConfigProvider.php file

Create a plugin to set custom value in checkoutConfig Json

```
public function afterGetConfig(\Magento\Checkout\Model\DefaultConfigProvider $subject, $result)
{
    $quoteId = $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote()->getId();

    $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    if ($quoteId) {
        $itemOptionCount = count($result['quoteItemData']);
        $quoteItems = $this->_quoteItemRepository->getList($quoteId);
        //$logger->info(print_R($itemOptionCount,1));

        $isbnOptions = [];
        foreach ($quoteItems as $index => $quoteItem) {
            $quoteItemId = $quoteItem['item_id'];
            $isbnOptions[$quoteItemId] = $quoteItem['isbn'];
        }

        for ($i=0; $i < $itemOptionCount; $i++) {
            $quoteParentId = $result['totalsData']['items'][$i]['item_id'];
            $currentOption = [];
            $isNew = null;
            $result['quoteItemData'][$i]['new'] = 'newvv';
            $productId = $result['quoteItemData'][$i]['product']['entity_id'];
            $productObj = $this->_productRepository->load($productId);
            $isNew = $productObj->getCustomAttribute();
            $result['quoteItemData'][$i]['new'] = $isNew;
            json_encode($currentOption);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Step 3 : Add custom atribute in JS file 
Put vendor file in theme Json

vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/item/details.js

```
define(
[
    'uiComponent'
],
function (Component) {
    "use strict";
    var quoteItemData = window.checkoutConfig.quoteItemData;
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/item/details'
        },
        quoteItemData: quoteItemData,
        getValue: function(quoteItem) {
            return quoteItem.name;
        },
        getItemTag: function(quoteItem) {
            var itemProduct = this.getItemProduct(quoteItem.item_id);
            return (itemProduct.new == true) ? 'new!' : null;
        },
        getItemProduct: function(item_id) {
            var itemElement = null;
            _.each(this.quoteItemData, function(element, index) {
                if (element.item_id == item_id) {
                    itemElement = element;
                }
            });
            return itemElement;
        }

    });
}
```

);

Step 4 : Copy below code in Html file to show in order summary
vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/template/summary/item/details.html

```
<span class="product-item-new" data-bind="text: getItemTag($parent)"></span>
```